# How do you call a controller action from a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a rails app that I am trying to use a model file that finds `@ mentions` in a text field and then I want it to notify the `@mentioned` party, using `after_create` callback

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :notifiy_users

  def notifiy_users
    mentioned_users.each do |user|
      Notification.create!(recipient: user,
                           actor: self.user,
                           action: 'mentioned',
                           notifiable: self)
    end
  end

  def mentions
    @mentions ||= begin
      regex = /@([\w]+)/
      matches = body.scan(regex).flatten
    end
  end

  def mentioned_users
    @mentioned_users ||= User.where(username: mentions)
  end
end
```

on `local_env` this works and the notification is created and saved, but when I push to production this acts like the `after_create` is never called and I get no return from the notify_users method.

Any help or recommendations for a better way to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in production, most likely your `mentioned_users` is empty.

Comment: where do you want to call controller action from model??

Comment: Calling a controller action from a model sounds like a bad idea. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling controller actions from inside a model violates [MVC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm). Model actions should only handle data-related logic, all the actions should stay within the controller.

Instead, you should be calling the callback from within your controller:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  after_action :notify_users, only: [:create]

  ...

  def notify_users
    @post.mentioned_users.each do |user|
      Notification.create!(recipient: user,
                     actor: @post.user, 
                     action: 'mentioned',
                     notifiable: self)
    end
  end

end
```

And your model will look like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  def mentions
    @mentions ||= begin
      regex = /@([\w]+)/
    matches = self.body.scan(regex).flatten
   end
  end

  def mentioned_users
    @mentioned_users ||= User.where(username: self.mentions)
  end

end
```